# How to add one window into another window?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpftoolkit

here i am want to add accountview.xaml to the accountlistview.xaml .i am try many option but i can not do it.
here accountlistview.xaml contain grid and accountview.xaml contain textbox.the code fo accountlistview.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyBooks.View.accountListView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:MyBooks.View"
xmlns:uic="clr-namespace:UIControls;assembly=UIControls"
xmlns:wpftoolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ViewResources.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions><wpftoolkit:DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Payments}"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPayment, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                         SelectionMode="Single"
                         IsReadOnly="True">
        <wpftoolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
            <wpftoolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                Header="{Resx ResxName=MyBooks.Properties.Strings, Key=Journal_Date_Label}"
                Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
            <wpftoolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                Header="{Resx ResxName=MyBooks.Properties.Strings, Key=Journal_CreditedParty_Label}"
                Binding="{Binding CreditedAccount.Name}"/>
            <wpftoolkit:DataGridTextColumn
                Header="{Resx ResxName=MyBooks.Properties.Strings, Key=Journal_Narration_Label}"
                Binding="{Binding Narration}"/>
        </wpftoolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    </wpftoolkit:DataGrid>
```

how to add accountview.xaml in this window?

Comment: Please be more specific about where do you want to add AccountView to. Do you want it to be an item for the container in AccountListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just include the following line in `AccountListView.xaml` :

```
<uic:AccountView.xaml />
```